# winston.debug does not show anything on terminal

Tags: node.js, terminal, console, winston

I am trying to debug a nodejs library which is using `winston` as logger. I can see the library is using `winston.debug` to log something.

But when I run the app, I can see the logs from `winston.info`, but not `winston.debug`.

Any insight to get the logs displayed on the console would be appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to set the log level inside the library in order to get it to print debug logs. Have a look at the "Usage" section on https://github.com/winstonjs/winston.

Comment: @Adaephon I can't do that because it's 3rd party dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through the same problem and one simple line intro launch.json help me.

```
"outputCapture": "std"
```

Hope i helped you, thanks!

Comment: You are a hero!!